# Create a form without creating a page

Tags: 7, forms

It seems simple enough to create a form in Drupal 7 with the Form API, however, everything I find shows that you have to use hook_menu() to add a page and then generate the form that way.

I would like to create a standalone form, then just display the form using drupal_get_form() and drupal_render() to render the form.

How do I create a custom form without creating it's own page?

Comment: Have you tried to simply omit the `hook_menu()` step? How it failed you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very simple...add a function to your module:

```
function MYMODULE_some_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // Build and return your form.
}
```

Call [`drupal_get_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) from whatever context makes sense to your use case, and render the result:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_some_form');
$rendered_form = drupal_render($form);
```

Then you can use `$rendered_form` as the output wherever it makes sense to do so (usually a template file).

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I knew it would be quite simple just couldn't find a good example. Cheers.